# How do I properly destroy a javascript timer object in a nested hover event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cleartimeout

I am having difficulty properly clearing a timer function from within a hover event.  I have two divs.  They are siblings and the next sibling should display on hover of the other.  I can't determine where I am messing up, but what I have figured out is that each time I hover over the main-item that it creates an entirely new timer with setTimeout.  So the first iteration works fine, a second hover will trigger twice and so forth.

```
    .main-item {
      width: 300px;
      height: 100px;
      background: #000;
    }

    .sub-item {
      display: none;
      width:450px;
      height: 75px;
      background: red;

      &.open {
        display: block;
      }

    }



    <div>
      <div class="main-item">
      </div>
      <div class="sub-item"></div>
    </div>

    var timer;

    $('.main-item').hover(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var $sub = $this.next();

      $sub.addClass('open');

}, function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $sub = $this.next();

  $sub.hover(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    clearTimeout($this.data('timerId'));
    timer = null;

    console.log(timer);

  }, function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      $this.removeClass('open');
      alert('this triggered');
    }, 2000);
    $this.data('timerId', timer);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue isn't the timer, but with binding event handlers.
Each time you mouse off of `.main-item` you bind a hover handler to `.sub-item`. You either need to remove the previous handler, or set a boolean to remember that you have binded the hover handler, or use the jquery function `one` with `mouseenter` and `mouseoff` events, there are many ways to solve this problem.

Using `$sub.off()` to remove previous handler.

https://jsfiddle.net/p2wtonac/2/

Using boolean to bind once.

https://jsfiddle.net/p2wtonac/3/

Comment: Thanks for that information.  I changed it out and that did the trick for my needs.